# MySQL, PHP - retrieve data from mysql and email it temperamental

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following cod which basically sends a message with some user data from MySQL. Now the thing is the email in question gets sent sometimes but not if I need to resend it. Here is the code:

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include("config.php");
//getting id of the data from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table_name Where id='$id'");

if($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$name = $res['name'];
$email = $res['email'];
$date = $res['date'];

if(empty($id)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Error: Did not send.</font><br/>";
        } else { 

// The message
        $message = "Hi $name,\r\n\r\nThis email is to inform you that your   
 \r\n\r\nRegards, \r\n Me.";



        $headers = 'From: no-reply@mydomain.org' . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: no-reply@mydomain.org' . "\r\n" .
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $Subject = 'Hello';

        // Send
        mail($email, $Subject, $message, $headers);
//display success message
echo "<font color='green'>Email sent successfully to $name.</font><br/>";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php' class='button button1 link'>Go Back to Overview</a>";
} 
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with 'not if i need to resend it'

Comment: @kerv I think he means that sometimes the email isn't send, and if thats the case, he wants to send it again (try to send as long it takes to success). For TO: I really recommend you using mysqli_* or PDO_* instead of mysql_* since they're deprecated

Comment: Sorry for not explaining correctly, before this is called I have a page which lists all users in the db and when I click on a link send email next to the specific user it gets its ID and calls the page withe the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and it was about `mail` function call failing sometimes:

You can add retry logic to your mail call:

```
$triesLeft = 5;
while ($triesLeft > 0) {
    $rc = mail(...);
    if ($rc === true) {
      break;
    }

    sleep(1); // Space to improve here - see exponential backoff, for instance
    $triesLeft -= 1;
} 

if ($triesLeft === 0) {
  // Log critical error
}
```

But this might and will introduce delays in your response time, and in some cases client will even get a timeout.

So usually the solution to this problem is not to send the email right away, but to quickly put it in any kind of queue (even simple db table will suffice), and then make another worker script that will send all that is unsent.

You can move this retry logic to this worker script and sleep all you want, it won't block client.

The only "downsides" to this solution is that:

1. You will not be able to show result of `mail` call to your client (which is useless anyway since it means only that is was "accepted for delivery", not actually delivered), and
2. You'll have a bit more moving parts and you'll have to write a bit more code. But it's either that or accepting that some of your mail calls will fail.

An outline of a solution might be:

```
form.php (gets called when customer submits form):

  get request parameters
  form email subject, body from request parameters
  save email to db with status = unsent

worker.php (should be always running in an infinite loop or something like that in background on server):

  get unsent email from db
  try to send it, retrying if needed
  if sent successfully - mark email as sent
  if failed to send - mark email an failed, log critical error, mitigate manually
```

Comment: Most major mail agents (such as postfix) have a built in queue so adding another one seems unnecessary. Assuming the script is correct, it's more likely that the emails are getting stuck in that mail queue instead.

Comment: Fair enough. But if one is using some email service, like SendGrid, directly via curl, this still might be helpful. I agree it's not the case in question, though.